# How to create a relationship of a new parent with an existing child in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My problem is that I have a order(child record) but the user(Parent record) doesn't exist yet. And I would like to send the order as a nested attribute in the user form.

Finding the order:

```
@order = Order.where(:paypal_express_token => params[:token]).last
```

Creating the user:

```
@user = User.new
```

Trying to create the relationship

```
if @order.user_id.blank?
  @order.user_id = @user.id
end
```

But it seems that it is wrong.

When creating children and parent at the same time, I can do this:

```
@user = User.new
@user.build_order
```

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to to use @MrYoshiji suggestion but I found another problem that I asked in this question: [Why the code doesn't appear in the html?... in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101900/why-the-code-doesnt-appear-in-the-html-in-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as following:

```
@order = Order.where(:paypal_express_token => params[:token]).last
@order.user ||= User.new # ||= will set user if @order.user returns nil OR false
# ...
@order.save # should save the user also
```

Comment: Is it necessary to save? Because I suppose I would have problems saving the user before sending to Devise