# Why the code doesn't appear in the html?... in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't know what is happening...
I'm trying to send hidden_fields with has_many association but the code doesn't appear in the html.

I'm sending the code. Probably it will be more clear

In the html.erb:

```
  <div id="billing_fields">
     <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-11 col-md-10 col-lg-7">
       <%= f.fields_for :orders do |field| %>
       <div class="field">
           <%= field.hidden_field :digital_product_plan_id, :value => @orders.digital_product_plan_id %>
           <%= field.hidden_field :express_payer_id, :value => @orders.express_payer_id %>
           <%= field.hidden_field :express_token, :value => @orders.express_token %>
       </div>
     <% end %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

It is generating this html:

```
<div id="billing_fields">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-11 col-md-10 col-lg-7">
  </div>
</div>
```

When I replace 
"f.fields_for :orders" 
with
"f.fields_for :order"
in the html.erb,  this html is generated (I was expecting something like that with the "orders" (previous) version)

```
  <div id="billing_fields">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-11 col-md-10 col-lg-7">
      <div class="field">
          <input id="user_order_digital_product_plan_id" name="user[order][digital_product_plan_id]" type="hidden" value="1" />
          <input id="user_order_express_payer_id" name="user[order][express_payer_id]" type="hidden" value="FVPYDJ7JCUY96" />
          <input id="user_order_express_token" name="user[order][express_token]" type="hidden" value="EC-32X744951C158904E" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The billing_fields is inside this form_for:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => registration_path(@user), html: {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"} do |f| %>
```

Order controller:

```
def new
  @user = current_user
  @orders = Order.where(:paypal_express_token => params[:token]).last
  @orders.get_details
  if ! @orders.paypal_email.blank?
    @orders.save!
  end
  if @user.nil?
    @user = User.new
    ...
  end
  @orders.user ||= @user 
end
```

Order model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

User model:

```
attr_accessible ... :orders_attributes
has_many :orders
accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders
```

I'm filling lost... Any hints?

This question deals with another aspect of this problem:
[How to create a relationship of a new parent with an existing child in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087988/how-to-create-a-relationship-of-a-new-parent-with-an-existing-child-in-rails/24088064#24088064)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

**`f.fields_for`**

You probably know this, but your `f.fields_for` call needs to be contained within a `form_for` method. Your HTML shows it on its own - if this by design, you need to put it inside a `form_for` block

---

`build`

Your real problem is likely with a lack of calling `build` on your associative data:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ActiveRecord::Base
   def new
       @user = User.new
       @user.orders.build #-> this should get f.fields_for to show
   end
end
```

Here is a [great resource](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through) detailing how this works

> Note from SevenSeaCat:
>
> it iterates over the user's orders outputting the fields, so it won't
>   output fields for orders if the user doesn't have any

Comment: good answer, but I'd add in a note like 'it iterates over the user's orders outputting the fields, so it won't output fields for orders if the user doesn't have any'

Comment: Thanks for answer and comment! But my problem now is that I don't know how to add an existing order to the user. The order exists without a user associated. This is the problem that I asked in my prior question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087988/how-to-create-a-relationship-of-a-new-parent-with-an-existing-child-in-rails/

I will look at the link that you sent and research more. But if you can solve this issue I would appreciate!